# Cloned inputs have no value - Combodate

Tags: jquery, input, clone, combodate

I'm using [Combodate](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/) to break up inputs for easier time entry. I'm also allowing multiple times to be entered. Issue is, cloned inputs don't receive a value.

Combodate appears to be initializing, but clearly not working properly and can be see here: https://jsfiddle.net/klav/xpvt214o/133229/

HTML

```
<button class="btn" id="btnAddDate">Add Time</button>

<div id="dateinfo1" class="clonedInput1 dashboard-item-frame">
    <button class="btn toggle pull-right">Show Input</button>
    <input type="text" style="display: block;" 
    data-format="h:mm A" data-template="h : mm A" class="start_time 
    combotime" name="start_time[0]" value="">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.combotime').combodate();

$('#btnAddDate').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var num     = $('.clonedInput1').length,
        newNum  = new Number(num + 1),
        newElem = $('#dateinfo' + num)
            .clone(true)
            .attr('id', 'dateinfo' + newNum)
            .fadeIn('slow');
        newNumLess  = newNum - 1;

        // Clear inputs
        newElem.find('input:text').val("").end();
        newElem.find('.start_time')
            .removeClass('combotime')
            .addClass('combotime').combodate();
        newElem.find('.start_time')
            .attr('name', 'start_time[' + newNumLess + ']')
            .val([]);

        $('#dateinfo' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
    });
```

Comment: It's fine for the initial value of the clone to be empty, but certainly want combodate translating selected values into the input value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed a couple of things to get it working but basically it seems that passing `true` to `.clone()` was preventing any new handlers from taking over the old ones, hence, and this is my assumption, the new call to `.combodate()` was not actually working and replacing the old elements like `span`.

### Changes

1. replace `.clone(true)` with `.clone()`
2. Remove old `span` tag
3. As a consequence of removing `true` param, the handlers are not passed down to the clone so,

   ```
   $('button.toggle').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('input').toggle();
       $(this).parent().find('.combodate').toggle();
   });
   ```

does not work and is replaced with

```
    //the important part here is the use of $(document).on()
    //instead of $('button.toggle').click().
    //using `.siblings()` is just some minor optimizing
    $(document).on('click', 'button.toggle', function(){
        $(this).siblings('input, .combodate').toggle();
    });
```

in order for the `.click()` handler be applied to any newly added `button.toggle`.

HIH

```js
$('.combotime').combodate();

$('#btnAddDate').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var num     = $('.clonedInput1').length,
  newNum  = new Number(num + 1),
  newElem = $('#dateinfo' + num).clone(/*removed true*/).attr('id', 'dateinfo' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
    
    //remove old span
    newElem.children('span').remove();
    
  newNumLess  = newNum - 1;
    
    //re-run .combodate()
  newElem.find('.start_time').val("").combodate();
    
  $('#dateinfo' + num).after(newElem);
  $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
 });
  
  //fix consequence of removing true param
  $(document).on('click', 'button.toggle', function(){
    //$(this).parent().find('input, .combodate').toggle();
    $(this).siblings('input, .combodate').toggle();
    
  });
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 20px;
}

#btnAddDate {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://smartsitterville.smartsitting.com/admin/dist/js/combodate.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">

<button class="btn" id="btnAddDate">
Add Time
</button>
<div id="dateinfo1" class="clonedInput1 dashboard-item-frame">
  <button class="btn toggle pull-right">Show Input</button>
  <input type="text" style="display: block;" data-format="h:mm A" data-template="h : mm A" class="start_time combotime" name="start_time[0]" value="">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would this mean for any other elements inside the clone -- a datepicker for instance? I thought true copies not just the element, but also the event handler.

Comment: @Klav;the problem is when you do `.clone(true)` you are telling the children to also keep the handlers of their originals, which in the case of `.combodate()` is conflicting with the new input/selects.the approach I proposed has indeed a big drawback: you will have to make sure each new clone is attached a proper handler, in order to remove this nuisance I encourage you to find some way of explicitly *removing* (maybe `.combodate('remove')`) and then re-attaching it again, you could look for something like that in the library's docs, please I would like to know if you find anything, good luck!

Comment: @Klav; if you indeed find such a way, you could then freely use `.clone(true)` and forget about re-attaching handlers in the future, which in this case only refers to `button.toggle`'s `.click()` event but could include other children in the future.